# Node RED. Sending several inputs to the same exec node

Tags: node-red

I am sending 3 sensor measurements coming from mqttin nodes to an exec command that must have this content `echo '1 2 3' | ./a.out` where 1 2 3 is the data from the 3 mqttin nodes.

I am having difficulties creating that command that must be sent from the exec node to the terminal.

Edited:

Basically I am first testing the use of several sliders, a join where I combine the payload of each slider as a string and a debug node to check the output. My objective is to create a single string with the values coming from the slider, and then add the last part of the command "...|./a.out"

The sliders are just pretending to be mqttin nodes. But in this part there is no problem.

I am not able even to cocatenate the outputs from the sliders, what should I create? buffer, string, array, key/value object.. and how to add the last part of the command?

I can execute something like `echo '1 2 3' | ./a.out` and the output is another string like "1231  13 2", with a varying number of spaces separating each number. How can i obtain 3 integers from that?

I have checked many related questions and didn't find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with and what have you tried ? I would guess you need to make sure all the data is in before you send the exec command, is that your problem ?

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to join the inputs and create such a string to be sent from exec. I just can't concatenate strings or even create an array with two inputs. I can't make correct use of the join node.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65239364/edit) the question to explain what you've tried with the join node and how it's not working.

Comment: Do you want a json of the flow?

Comment: You can include it, but a description of what you've tried and how it doesn't work is what's needed. Please read the doc on what a good SO question should contain: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, I have added some info now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exact output you want it's probably going to take multiple nodes.

- First up a join node set to output a key/value object

[image]

- next a function node to convert the 3 values into the string and add on the echo and pipe

e.g.

```
var keys = Object.keys(msg.payload)
var string = "echo '"
for (var k in keys) {
    string += msg.payload[keys[k]] + " "
}

msg.payload = string + "' | ./a.out";
return msg;
```